# Vuejs testing library - how to write a test to handle axios request in "mounted" hook

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library

I have a vue component that fetches data from an api in the "created" function. I'm just getting up and running using the following testing stack:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^5.8.2",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

My current test:

```
import BatchCalendar from '../src/components/batch_calendar.vue';
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue';

test('It renders correctly and loads initial data', done => {
    const wrapper = await render(BatchCalendar);

        
    getByText('Calendar Notices');
});
```

I know that vue testing library abstracts some methods away from the core vue testing utilities, so I'm left with using the "render" method of vue testing library.

My question is how should I go about handling the API call in the vue created hook.

1. Should all api calls (and also async methods?) be mocked?
2. How/where do I place await/async functions?
3. If I have a plugin (fullcalendar) that is making API requests on its own when rendering, how would I go about mocking/handling that?

Let me know if you need more info, thanks.

Comment: 1. yes 2. in `test`, you shouldn't use `done` for asynchronous tests, it's obsolete 3. preferably mock third-party libs in unit tests because they aren't your units. You won't naturally have the problem with testing with axios this way

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks so much for response. 1) Would you be able to throw a quick example together with the pieces that should get me to the end result? 2) My problem with the fullcalendar plugin is that I cannot control that it fires requests and then my tests throw errors/warnings. I'm wondering if there is a way I can shortcut them or swallow them.

Comment: Sorry, can't come up with full example. Basically you need to mock axios for your own requests, mock fullcalendar entirely or almost entirely (you shouldn't pollute your tests with third party libs but this especially applies to dom-oriented libs that Jest fake dom cannot handle), depending on how it's used, wait a bit for mocked response before asserting the result, e.g with `flush-promises`.